# Wagatail 2.1 (Django) Custom settings access from Snippet

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

So i have some settings that i need to be configured from the interface.

```
@register_setting
class TierPricingSettings(BaseSetting):
    Monday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Tuesday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Wednesday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Thursday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Friday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Saturday = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Sunday = models.CharField(max_length=255)


content_panels_english = [
    FieldPanel('Monday'),
    FieldPanel('Tuesday'),
    FieldPanel('Wednesday'),
    FieldPanel('Thursday'),
    FieldPanel('Friday'),
    FieldPanel('Saturday'),
    FieldPanel('Sunday'),
]
```

However i cannot seem to access these values from a snippet ? This is because the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/settings.html)  states you can only access it through using python

```
 my_settings = TierPricingSettings.for_site(request.site)
```

However snippets do not have access to the request object. How can i achieve having settings configurable from the admin panel and have those values accessible in snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The wagtail.contrib.settings module works on the basis that each site on your Wagtail installation has its own set of settings. Snippets have no built-in notion of belonging to a particular site (and, more generally, model code should work independently of the current request), so here we need some other way of identifying which site's settings to look up.

If you're only running a single site on this Wagtail instance and have no intention of adding any more, you can use the following to tell it to pick up the settings from the one and only site:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Site

my_settings = TierPricingSettings.for_site(Site.objects.first())
```

If you have multiple sites (or might do so in future), but you want a global `TierPricingSettings` object to apply everywhere, the best approach is to set one of your sites as the 'default site' under Settings -> Sites, and ensure you have that site selected when filling in the `TierPricingSettings` in the admin. Then look up the appropriate site as follows:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Site

my_settings = TierPricingSettings.for_site(Site.objects.get(is_default_site=True))
```

If you do want the settings to vary depending on the currently active site, you'll need to either update your snippet model to have an explicit concept of belonging to a site (e.g. add a foreign key to `Site`), or do all your pricing calculations in a method that receives the site object as an argument.